# How to find which node was clicked and remove its parent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, xhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.delete").click{function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
</script>

<li>
    <a href="index.html">
        <h3>1</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "" id = "我" class = "delete">删除关注</a>
</li>
```

but when i click that button ,"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" appears in the console.How can I make it ,i'm very puzzled.if possible , I want some example code ,a lot of thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a specific `<ul>` to target, use it's class name or ID to specify

```
$(function(){
    $('ul').on('click','a.delete',function(){
        $(this).closest('li').remove()
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XV2CY/)

Comment: using this function,i got a "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'".Can you write it more completely please,appreciate a lot

Comment: thanks a lot . but its not what I need.I've made it, its really an easy answer as below.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $( document ).bind("click", function( e ) {
     $( e.target ).closest("a.delete").parent().remove();
   });
    </script>

Comment: first, please use jQuery 1.7 on my answer. previous versions don't have the `.on()`. and what you just did is just similar to what i did - that was add a click handler to delete, find the parent (which is `<li>`) and remove it.